# Python - How to write log to an already existing Kibana?

Tags: python, logstash, kibana

Well I was asked to write `log` to an existing Kibana.

I was given a `host` and a `port`, I suppose that is the `host` and `port` of log stash.

I was told to search about how to send `log` to that host. That's all.

I have been researching but can not do anything.

My code so far:

```
import logging
from logging import StreamHandler
import logstash
import sys

host = '1**.**.**.***'   #this is the host I was given.

test_logger = logging.getLogger('venus-local')
test_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
test_logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(host, 5000, version=1))
test_logger.addHandler(StreamHandler())

try:
    test_logger.error('venus-local: test logstash error message.')
    test_logger.info('venus-local: test logstash info message.')
    test_logger.warning('venus-local: test logstash warning message.')

    # add extra field to logstash message
    extra = {
        'test_string': 'python version: ' + repr(sys.version_info),
        'test_boolean': True,
        'test_dict': {'a': 1, 'b': 'c'},
        'test_float': 1.23,
        'test_integer': 123,
        'test_list': [1, 2, '3'],
    }
    test_logger.info('venus-local: test extra fields', extra=extra)
except:
    print("Error")
```

When I run the above code, there is no error, it works (with no exception). But there is no change on the Kibana.

Comment: Do all your functions throw exceptions on error?  Perhaps there is a function return you should be capturing and checking.

Comment: I think that you will need to ask for more information to who gave you the host and port. Is it really logstash? What is the input? What is the pipeline?  What is the message format you need to send? You could be sending your messages to a pieline that has filters that could be dropping it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works in general.

Source -> Logstash pipeline (input plugins to accept inputs from source -> filter to perform some processing on data -> output plugin to send to elasticsearch) -> elasticsearch (As Database) -> kibana (As UI)

So, depending on logstash input plugin configured, your source may need different config to send to logstash.

You can also try to use TCPHandler directly from logging.handlers with logstash server host and port as input.